# Rails 4: Passing a variable from controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and have been confused by this problem for a while.

I'm looking to create a translation app. When a user clicks a link containing a word, I want the rails controller to get the translation through an external API call, save the word and translation, and then display the translation, all without refreshing the page.

The particular issue I have is getting some string (which will be the translation) to be passed from the controller to a js file, where it can then update the HTML to display the translation.

In the controller (texts_controller.rb):

```
def createword
    @word = Word.new(word_params)
    @word.save
    @translation = "Some string"
    respond_to do |format|
         format.js
    end
end
```

In the javascript (createword.js.erb)

```
console.log("done");
$(".message").html(<%= @translation %>);
```

When I delete the second line containing @translation, the javascript works just fine and logs "done" to the console. However, when I do include that line, none of it works.

How can I get this variable to the js, or if that is not possible, what is the best way to get it to the view?

Comment: I suggest to use `$.text` instead : `$(".message").text("<%= @translation %>");`, unless some of your translations are written in HTML, otherwise it could lead to potential XSS attacks. Eg, let's say some user stores a translation `<p onclick="doSomethingBad()">Click me to see the translation !</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try this, but adding some quotes will probably do what you want:

```
$(".message").text("<%= @translation %>");
```